# how to give & in android:digits property of xml in android

Tags: android, xml

I want to give 
android:digits="&" in xml layout.
but is it giving me errors.
I have also tried 
android:digits="&amp"
But still it is not working.
Please let me kn how to write this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes,but using that also it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <EditText 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:digits="&amp;"  />
```

This works very well for me. Even multiple times input of same digit as mentioned.

Comment: Hey thanks it worked.I was doing android:digits="&amp";

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Developer API Docs

> Accepts the digits 0 through 9, plus the minus sign (only at the beginning) and/or decimal point (only one per field) if specified.

It doe snot appear as if using `Digits` you can also use an `&`